# Не отображаются данные из БД в RecyclerView

Tags: android, room

Пытаюсь вывести в `RecyclerView` данные из БД используя Room. Но в `RecyclerView` ничего не отображается, и ошибок никаких нет.

Адаптер RoomAdapter

```
public class RoomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RoomAdapter.RoomViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private List<Bluda> bludaList;
    private List<Bluda> mFilteredList;
    private Context context;

    OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(long id);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    public class RoomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView txtName;
        public TextView txtIngredients;
        public RoundedImageView imgIcon;

        public RoomViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            txtIngredients = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtIngredients);
            imgIcon = (RoundedImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                default:
                    mItemClickListener.onItemClick(mFilteredList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
            }
        }
    }

    public RoomAdapter(Context context, List<Bluda> bludaList) {
        this.bludaList = bludaList;
        this.mFilteredList = bludaList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public RoomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new RoomViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RoomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Bluda bluda = mFilteredList.get(position);
        holder.txtName.setText(bluda.getName());
        holder.txtIngredients.setText(bluda.getIngredients());

        Glide.with(context).load(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/img/" + bluda.getImage() + ".png")).into(holder.imgIcon);

    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mFilteredList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

                String charString = charSequence.toString();

                if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                    mFilteredList = bludaList;
                } else {

                    List<Bluda> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (Bluda bludo : bludaList) {

                        if (bludo.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {

                            filteredList.add(bludo);
                        }
                    }

                    mFilteredList = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mFilteredList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                mFilteredList = (ArrayList<Bluda>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Фрагмент, куда пытаюсь вывести данные

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment implements RoomAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    RoomAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView rvList;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        BludaDao bludaDao = (BludaDao) AppDatabase.createPersistentDatabase(getContext().getApplicationContext()).bludaDao();

        bludaDao.getAll(1).observe(this, (List<Bluda> bludaList) -> {
            adapter = new RoomAdapter(getContext(), bludaList);
            adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            rvList.setAdapter(adapter);
        });



    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(long id) {
        Intent bludodActivity = new Intent(getActivity(), BludoActivity.class);
        bludodActivity.putExtra("id", id);
        startActivity(bludodActivity);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);



        rvList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rvList);
        rvList.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 1));
        rvList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

        return view;
    }

}
```

Интерфейс BludaDao

```
@Dao
public interface BludaDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM bluda WHERE categoryID = :categoryID")
    public LiveData<List<Bluda>> getAll(long categoryID); 

    @Query("SELECT * FROM bluda WHERE id = :id")
    Maybe<Bluda> getById(long id);
}
```

Класс описывающий объект и таблицу

```
@Entity
public class Bluda {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String ingredients;
    public String description;
    public String icon;
    public String image;
    public String favorite;
    public int categoryID;

    public Bluda(String name, String ingredients, String description, String icon, String image, String favorite, int categoryID) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
        this.description = description;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.image = image;
        this.favorite = favorite;
        this.categoryID = categoryID;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getIngredients() {
        return ingredients;
    }

    public void setIngredients(String ingredients) {
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getFavorite() {
        return favorite;
    }

    public void setFavorite(String favorite) {
        this.favorite = favorite;
    }

    public int getCategoryID() {
        return categoryID;
    }

    public void setCategoryID(int categoryID) {
        this.categoryID = categoryID;
    }
}
```

Класс для работы с БД

```
@Database(entities = {Bluda.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract BludaDao bludaDao();

    private static final String DB_NAME = "kitchen.db";

    public static AppDatabase createPersistentDatabase(Context context) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, DB_NAME)
                .openHelperFactory(new AssetSQLiteOpenHelperFactory())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте точку останова в подписке 
`bludaDao.getAll(1).observe(this, (List<Bluda> bludaList) -> {
            adapter = new RoomAdapter(getContext(), bludaList);
            adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            rvList.setAdapter(adapter);
        });`
- и проверьте приходят ли сюда данные. Может у Вас просто нет данных по первой категории. И еще - не нужно каждый раз создавать новые адаптер при получении данных. Достаточно обновлять данные в самом адаптере.